# fatal: cannot exec 'hooks/update': Permission denied when using Git

Tags: git, solaris, acl

We have a Solaris server in our campus where every student and staff has an account on. I want to host a bare Git repo and have it only accessible to certain users.

Now, because I do not administrate the server, I cannot mess around with the groups and user accounts. I know I can use Giotlite and create public keys for my users but it seems silly since they already have their own user accounts on the server. So what I am doing is to use FACL to give access to specific users.

Here is what I did to set up the repo using `cs101` account on its home directory (it's the course account):

1. I created a directory for the repo: `mkdir cs101.git`
2. Set the FACL permissions using to give access to my user account

   ```
   setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::---,d:o:---,d:m:rwx cs101.git
   setfacl -m d:u:cs101:rwx,u:cs101:rwx,d:u:welcomb:rwx,u:welcomb:rwx cs101.git
   ```
3. Then finally initialize Git

   ```
   cd cs101.git
   git init --bare --shared
   ```

The directory listing shows

```
total 88
drwx--S---+  7 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  3 14:33 .
drwx-----x   6 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  5 15:02 ..
drwxrws---+  2 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  3 14:33 branches
-rw-rw----+  1 cs101    cs101       126 Aug  3 14:33 config
-rw-rw----+  1 cs101    cs101        73 Aug  3 14:33 description
-rw-rw----+  1 cs101    cs101        23 Aug  3 14:33 HEAD
drwxrws---+  2 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  3 14:33 hooks
drwxrws---+  2 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  3 14:33 info
drwxrws---+ 33 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  5 15:10 objects
drwxrws---+  4 cs101    cs101      4096 Aug  3 14:33 refs
```

Permission for the directories seems correct

```
# file: hooks/
# owner: cs101
# group: cs101
user::rwx
user:cs101:rwx                #effective:rwx
user:welcomb:rwx              #effective:rwx
group::rwx                    #effective:rwx
mask:rwx
other:---
default:user::rwx
default:user:cs101:rwx
default:user:welcomb:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask:rwx
default:other:---
```

Still using the course account `cs101`, I push some files into the repo.

Now, I logout of the course account and login using my own user account and I am able to clone the repo `welcomb@solaris$ git clone ~cs101/cs101.git`

So far so good, everything appears fine.

Now the problem is that I am unable to push new commits back to the repo using my own user account:

```
welcomb@solaris$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push
trace: built-in: git 'push'
trace: run_command: 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/course/cs101'\'''
trace: exec: '/bin/bash' '-c' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/course/cs101'\''' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/course/cs101'\'''
trace: built-in: git 'receive-pack' '/home/course/cs101'
trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '-q'
trace: exec: 'git' 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '-q'
trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '-q'
trace: run_command: 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3' '-q'
remote: trace: exec: 'git' 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3' '-q'
remote: trace: built-in: git 'unpack-objects' '--pack_header=2,3' '-q'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: run_command: 'hooks/update' 'refs/heads/master' '629b5b1f0122de95bd4e7b50a7968e64aaef6e65' 'b2072da84ee7d3fde6c6daf2cae61dbae6b0a5d9'
fatal: cannot exec 'hooks/update': Permission denied
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
trace: exec: 'git' 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto' '--quiet'
To /home/course/cs101
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/course/cs101'
```

It seems it is unable to execute `hooks/update`.

```
fatal: cannot exec 'hooks/update': Permission denied
```

But `hooks/update` exec bit is
not even set, which mean Git should ignore running it.

```
/home/course/cs101/cs101.git/hooks$ getfacl update         

# file: update                                               
# owner: cs101                                             
# group: cs101                                             
user::rw-                                                    
user:cs101:rwx          #effective:rwx                       
user:welcomb:rwx        #effective:rwx               
group::rw-              #effective:rw-                       
mask:rwx                                                     
other:---                                                    

/home/course/cs101/cs101.git/hooks$ ls -al update          
-rw-rw----   1 cs101    cs101        2910 Aug  4 10:50 update
```

I can access the files in the directories and even execute `update.sample` using my account

```
/home/course/cs101/cs101.git/hooks$ ./update.sample
Don't run this script from the command line.
 (if you want, you could supply GIT_DIR then run
  ./update.sample <ref> <oldrev> <newrev>)
```

So I can't figure out why Git push is failing to update the repo.

Comment: The output from `getfacl` suggests that it *is* executable for `user:welcomb`, so Git would attempt to execute it. It's not clear why that would subsequently fail (is it interpreted? given the small file size, I imagine so; if so, is the interpreter's permission denied?).

Comment: The umask for `update` is not executable, and indeed I cannot execute it from the terminal. Do you think Git thinks it's executable from the acl and tries to run it? And how do I check if it's interpreted? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Git calls `access(path, X_OK)` so it depends on what the system's `access` call returns, but I would expect it to prefer the ACLs over the `stat` mode bits. As for what it means to be an interpreted file, see https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

Comment: Yes! Removing the ACL execute permission solved it. Seems like there's a bit of disconnect between what `access` returns and what can actually be done on Solaris. I don't think Linux has this issue since I all the Linux tutorials I googled seems fine. You want to submit an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getfacl` output includes the lines:

```
user:cs101:rwx          #effective:rwx      
user:welcomb:rwx        #effective:rwx
```

which means that the C library `access(path, X_OK)` function is likely to claim that the file *can* be executed (run via an `execve` system call or similar), at least for users `cs101` and `welcomb`.  This is how Git determines whether a hook is executable.

(Note that any *other* user calling `access` will get the answer: *no, this file is not executable*.  This is part of what makes ACLs so complicated.)

When the OS actually tries to execute it, however, something else goes wrong.  It's not entirely clear precisely *what* goes wrong, but the `execve` system call fails with a "permission denied" error.  Git then decides to that hook failed, rather than that the hook was not actually executable (Git assumes that `access` will say *no* rather than *yes* for these cases).

Given the tiny size of the file (2910 bytes, from the `ls -al update` output) it seems unlikely that the `update` hook is anything other than a shell script.  If it *is* a shell script, it needs a correct `#!` interpreter line to be executable, and that interpreter line must point to a file that itself has execute permissions.

If you do want the hook to run, you will have to trace down the source of the actual failure.  If you *don't* want the hook to run, and don't want Git to *think* the hook *should* run, remove the execute bits from the various elements of the ACL, or remove the ACL entirely (ACLs and "Unix style" permissions are often separate entities in the underlying system, though ZFS is different here).